# Get Current Firestore API Calls

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to fetch (via iOS) the current number of **Firestore API requests** an app has used for the day / week / billing cycle?

---

I'm trying to see if I can fetch this value to display it to the user. I know some database services offer this as a service in order to determine how many requests are remaining.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such client API available.  You are always free to [file a feature request](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).